# How to set delay on mouseover for this menu?

Tags: jquery, delay, hoverintent

I have drop down menu, and I want to add delay on mouseout. So when you hover over the menu, it ll display drop down, but when you move mouse from the menu, I want to there be some delay.

I have searched all day for this, and didnt found anything, expect hoverIntent plugin which i dont know to use.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<ul id='nav'>
  <li><a href='#'>Top level 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Top level 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Sub 2 - 1</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Sub 2 - 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href='#'>Sub 2 - 2 - 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub 2 - 2 - 1 - 1</a></li>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub 2 - 2 - 1 - 2</a></li>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub 2 - 2 - 1 - 3</a></li>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub 2 - 2 - 1 - 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href='#'>Sub 2 - 2 - 2</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href='#'>Sub 2 - 2 - 3</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub 2 - 2 - 3 - 1</a></li>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub 2 - 2 - 3 - 2</a></li>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub 2 - 2 - 3 - 3</a></li>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub 2 - 2 - 3 - 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'>Sub 2 - 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){                   
    $("#nav ul ").css({display: "none"}); 
    $("#nav li").hover(
        function()
            {
                $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideToggle();
            },
        function(){
          $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
        }
);
```

Please assume, that I'm big noob for javascript :)

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I have tried all the solutions, and none worked expect the solution from Patricia. Now i get strange behavior as you can see at http://pastehtml.com/view/aykmhy9ae.html

Comment: I saw plenty of perfectly valid answers below.   You should post a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that everyone can all see and play with the same code.

Answer (score 1):

This adds a 5 second (5000 ms) delay...

```
$(this).find('ul:first').delay(5000).css({visibility: "hidden"});
```

---

**EDIT:**

[Read more here.](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest that a gradual fade out is better than a delay. In which case, try the following instead of your `visibility: "hidden"` code

```
$(this).find('ul:first').fadeOut('slow');
```

A small tip: When you're displaying/hiding elements using jQuery, you only need use the following:

```
hide(), show(), toggle()
fadeIn(), fadeOut(), fadeToggle()
slideIn(), slideOut(), slideToggle()
```

Setting `display` and `visibility` CSS properties is futile.

Answer (score 0):

you'd want something like this:

```
        $("#nav li").hoverIntent({
            over: function(e){
               $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideToggle();

            },
            out:function(e){
                $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});

            },
            timeout: 1000
        });
```

where 1000 is the number of milliseconds you want to have the delay of the mouseout action

Comment: There is delay, but somehow strange :)
Now i get strange behavior as you can see at http://pastehtml.com/view/aykmhy9ae.html

Comment: very interesting, i think some of your css hover behaviour is interfering, but i'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Im looking in CSS as cow :D
Im considering to switch to another menu script.. Do you have any suggestion? My requirements are that it work also without JS, to work in IE7.. Also it must be lightweight :)

Comment: i've had some success with potato menu.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use settimeout to delay the function from firing, and also make sure that if they hover away the timeout is cleared. This will do a 1000ms timeout.

```
$(document).ready(function(){                   
    $("#nav ul ").css({display: "none"}); 
    var onHoverTimeoutFunction = null;
    $("#nav li").hover(
        function()
            {
                onHoverTimeoutFunction = setTimeout(function() {$(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideToggle();},1000);
            },
        function(){
          clearTimeout(onHoverTimeoutFunction);
          $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function () {
        var timer = null;
        $("li", "#nav").hover(
            function () {
                var element = $(this);
                timer = window.setTimeout(function () { element.find("ul:first").slideToggle(); }, 500);
            },
            function () { window.clearTimeout(timer); $(this).find('ul:first').slideToggle(); }
        );

            $("ul", "#nav").css("display", "none");
    });
```